# How to force the number/float delimiter upon opening excel with openpyxl?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl, number-formatting

Using openpyxl/py3.7 64bit (Win10, 64bit).

How do i enforce the number delimiter format upon opening an excel file?
I read multiple files from all over the world and receive unspecified and varying number formats such as 
"1.000,00" (US Style) "1000.00" (US Style without thousands delim) as well as "1000,00" (German Style) amongst others.

How can i enforce either of those styles (preferrably the latter upon opening and/or writing the excel file?)

Pseudo code:

```
load_workbook(myfile, data_only=True, mynumberformat=X)
```

from https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.reader.excel.html i get that this is not possible.

What is the most generic and pythonic way to achieve a common float format on cell or worksheet or workbook level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styles must *+always** be applied on a per cell basis. Ideally I'd used a named style for this kind of thing but you'll have to write your own code to find and format the relevant cells

Comment: So there is no way to enforce country default settings during opening of a file, that is very unfortunate. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with country defaults.

Comment: So maybe this is either a misunderstanding or i do not get it. If i receive an Excel file from the US with US naming conventions, i am unable to apply US-formula-terminology (e.g. SUM <> SUMME), Excel is simply unable to evaluate the formula. The german formula input however, cannot handle some US floating point formats. There is some kind of country preferences that i don't get at all. Meanwhile, i read everything using openpyxl, change evertyhing to the desired format and output to new files, which is extra effort.